# Como verificar se data esta cadastrada através do MontheCalendar ? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

Fala galera bom dia!

Estou com uma pequena dificuldade em relação uso do MontheCalendar...

Eu tenho um sistema de agendamento por DATA, que após o cadastramento do determinado evento, ele é apresentado no DATAGRIDVIEW,com seguinte codigo

```
`public void GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                cg.con = new SqlConnection(cn.DBconn);
                cg.con.Open();
                cg.cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT RTRIM(Id),RTRIM(Nome) ,RTRIM(Endereco), RTRIM(Quadra), RTRIM(Lote), RTRIM(Telefone), RTRIM(Celular),(Data), RTRIM(Hora), RTRIM(Email), RTRIM(Observacao), RTRIM(Locacao), RTRIM(Evento),  RTRIM(Estado) from Eventos order by Data", cg.con);
                cg.rdr = cg.cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                DGW_Agenda.Rows.Clear();


                while (cg.rdr.Read() == true)
                {
                    DGW_Agenda.Rows.Add(cg.rdr[0], cg.rdr[1], cg.rdr[2], cg.rdr[3], cg.rdr[4], cg.rdr[5], cg.rdr[6], cg.rdr[7], cg.rdr[8], cg.rdr[9], cg.rdr[10], cg.rdr[11], cg.rdr[12], cg.rdr[13]);
                }

                cg.con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }`
```

O que eu gostaria é que quando eu clicasse em alguma data no monthercalendar ele checasse ao meu datagridview  na coluna 'DATA DE AGENDAMENTO' se a data esta agendada, ou data disponivel para cadastramento.

Segue o print da tela do sistema para melhor entendimento.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o código onde está? Você não consegue checar no `DataSource`, você quer que ao selecionar uma data ele avise que não está disponível ou desabilitar as datas indisponíveis na seleção? O sistema vai ser utilizado por vários usuários? Está fazendo algum controle de consistência? Elabore mais a sua pergunta apresentando um [MCVE]

Comment: Olá @LeandroAngelo eu não consigo checar ele no meu datasource, pesquisei alguns foruns como fazer essa checagem, mas estou um pouco perdido. A ideia é somente verificar se a data esta cadastrada de acordo com o evento cadastrado! fazendo a verificação na coluna do datasource.

Comment: não entendi porque você não consegue consultar o datasource... mas de qualquer forma se que apresente o código, não tem como ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Sem que apresente o seu código e estrutura não como detalhar mais, mas veja o exemplo abaixo de uma abordagem que pode lhe ajudar...

Estrutura hipotética da sua model para os agendamentos:

```
public class Agendamento
{
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAgendamento { get; set; }
}
```

Estrutra do formulário popuplando a `DataGridView` e já com o bind do evento de seleção para o `MonthCalendar`, compartilhando a mesma source para validação...

```
public partial class Main : Form
{

    private List<Agendamento> agendamentosDataSource { get; set; } = new List<Agendamento>();

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Simulando uma consulta para popular a lista de agendamentos
        agendamentosDataSource.AddRange(
            new List<Agendamento>() {
                new Agendamento{ Local = "Teste 1", DataAgendamento = DateTime.Parse("18/04/2019") },
                new Agendamento{ Local = "Teste 2", DataAgendamento = DateTime.Parse("19/04/2019") },
            });

        //Apontando o DataSource da Grid para a lista
        grdPessoas.DataSource = agendamentosDataSource;

    }

    private void mcSelecionaData_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataSelecionada = (sender as MonthCalendar).SelectionStart;

        //Utilizando a mesma lista do DataSource da Grid para recuperar as datas reservadas.          
        var datasReservadas = agendamentosDataSource.Select(x => x.DataAgendamento);

        //Validação e feedback simples para o usuário...
        if (datasReservadas.Contains(dataSelecionada))
            MessageBox.Show("Essa Data já foi reservada");

    }
```

Comment: Fala Leandro Angelo Obrigado pela sua ajuda, eu reformulei a pergunta para melhor entendimento do problema srsrs. eu ja tenho a forma de apresentação dos dados do datagridview so nao sei como fazer essa checagem pelo monthercalendar